# How to record Screen in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, record

I have some problems how can record customer screen in the Shopify platform?

So I want to record user's screen when they click something in Shopify website

Comment: Record screen? isn't it against the security policy?

Comment: I think no because we just get information user click in Shopify website. Some app is similar, such as lucky orange.

Comment: That's not screen recording... Its called event tracking.. and for that you can easily use google analytics ... with ga.js